# Пример реализации паттерна MVP на Android с фрагментами

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, mvp

Не могу найти пример реализации паттерна MVP с Fragment под Android на Java  без сторонних библиотек.
Может быть у кого завалялся? 
Я представлял это себе в виде Presenter, который командует Activity - какой фрагмент загрузить.

Попробовал разобраться с примерами в данном репозитории и там не так, как мне представлялось:
https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

1. Запускается TasksActivity.
2. В активити создается TasksPresenter.
3. Создается специальный класс ActivityUtils с методом addFragmentActivity() куда передаются в качестве аргументов SupportFragmentManager, TasksFragment, контейнер под Fragment, находящийся в TasksActivity
4. В методе onCreate TasksActivity используется ActivityUtils.addFragmentActivity(), после чего в контейнер под фрагмент внутри TasksActivity загружается TasksFragment.
5. В самом TasksFragment есть кнопка, которая стартует другую Activity, внутри которой так же есть контейнер под Fragment, куда собственно и загружается следующий фрагмент.

Не понимаю, зачем это вообще?
Почему бы не работать тогда напрямую с Activity, ведь нет выгоды от использования Fragment.
Вряд ли это неправильный пример архитектуры, кажется репозиторий сотрудника Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите, если у вас к примеру 1-2 фрагмента на активити, то тут вполне можно обойтись и одним презентером на активити, которая рулит фрагментами внутри нее. Хотя если фрагменты имеют сложную логику то лучше все же каждому фрагменту сделать свой презентер.

Если же у вас сингл активити, то там в целом обычно по презентеру на фрагмент, причем не исключен презентер на активити, если в ней есть какая-то общая логика.

Насчет навигации. Я бы не стал выносить навигацию в презентер. Лучше для этого создать отдельную сущность, которая возможно, но не обязательно будет лежать в презентере, а тот в свою очередь будет ей делегировать навигацию. Так же если вас интересует навигация с фрагментами, то стоит посмотреть в Navigation Component от Google или Cicerone от Yandex.

В примере который вы скинули вообще не используется MVP. Там ViewModel, разница ее в том, что в отличии от презентера она ничего не знает о View. А все View работают с ней через подписку. И если с MVP мы имеем обычно по презентеру на экран, то VieModel может шариться на несколько экранов и разделяются они скорее не по экранам, а по логике внутри нее. Например в одном экране может быть 2 и более ViewModel-ей.

В качестве навигации в примере как раз и используется Navigation Component. И они имеют ViewModel которая и отвечает за навигацию. И по сути что происходит, на эту ViewModel подписана активити, она в свою очередь ждет когда ViewModel запостит какие-то изменения и реагирует на них(открывает новый скрин). А другие фрагменты просто постят эту ViewModel экран который необходимо открыть. Так вся логика навигации находится в одном месте и может быть вызвана откуда угодно. И если вы вдруг захотите что-то поменять в принципе навигации, то вся ваша логика будет в одном месте.

Надеюсь я дал ответ на ваш вопрос=)

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш комментарий очен полезен.